# SQL: Creating Dynamic Fiscal Quarters

Tags: sql, t-sql, date

I have a set of data which includes an account #, and a fiscal end date. The fiscal end date does not always match the calendar year. I need to take the given fiscal end date and generate the quarters based on it. For example, if fiscal end date equals 6/31 then the first quarter would be 7/01 thru 9/30, second would be 10/1 thru 12/31, etc.

The only way I can currently think to do this would be a very long and complicated if/then structure. Any help making something more efficient would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: FYI... 6/31 is not a valid date. Also, show what queries you have now.

Comment: Check out DATEFROMPARTS functions in T-SQL. That might help.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. It's also helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DATEADD() function

```
select convert(varchar(10),dateadd(day,1,'6/25/2016'),101) as startdate,
convert(varchar(10),dateadd(month,3,dateadd(day,1,'6/25/2016')),101) as enddate
```

Result will be like:

[image]